# Selenium FirefoxDriver on Linux - org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, driver

I have a problem with Firefox Driver on Linux(Raspbian). When I execute the .jar file that uses Selenium Firefox starts, but nothing else happens and it throws an exception:

> java -jar SeleniumTest.jar
>
> 1505501625875   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
>   1505501625975   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:25640
>   1505501628065   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox with args ["-marionette"]
>
> (firefox-esr:1547): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>
> (firefox-esr:1547): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>
> (firefox-esr:1547): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>
> (firefox-esr:1547): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>   1505501636367   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 46791
>
> (/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr:1607): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>
> (/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr:1607): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>
> (/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr:1607): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>
> (/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr:1607): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'raspberrypi', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version: '4.9.35-v7+', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:243)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:139)
>       at base.Main.testGoogleSearch(Main.java:17)
>       at base.Main.main(Main.java:10)

It's hard to overcome because:

- I found a possible solution - update Selenium. Had the same exception on Windows and compiling with a newer version of Selenium libraries solved the problem. It doesn't solve it on my Raspberry pi.
- Geckodriver and Firefox seem to be totally okay since I can run them using python.

I don't use Selenium Grid, I just want java application to perform some actions on the browser like it does when I put a driver .exe file with the .jar on windows.
Maybe useful information: I compile the code to jar on Windows and only run it on Linux: java -jar SeleniumTest.jar

The line that causes the exception:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: From your description, you wrap selenium-standalone-server.jar, your script, webdriver.exe  in one file: SeleniumTest.jar,  and you copy this file to a linux and execute it by java -jar SeleniumTest.jar?

Comment: @yong I explained it wrong in my previous deleted comment. I don't use selenium server. It's all supposed to be run locally. I build jar file from Selenium libraries on Windows and try to run it on linux using "java -jar SeleniumTest.jar". Firefox and geckodriver is installed on linux.

Comment: I would check compatibility between the versions of Firefox, geckodriver, and Selenium that you're using. If it runs in Python with the same Geckodriver and Firefox executables, then are you sure your Java Selenium library supports them both?